# Can't post data in login form

Tags: node.js, post, httprequest

I am trying to create a REST API for my school site at http://www.ss18324.scuolanext.info/.

Once you click on this custom site (which is different for each school) you will be redirected to another page where you will be asked to insert the login data.

`var request = require('request');

 request.post('https://www.portaleargo.it/argoweb/famiglia/common/login_form2.jsp', 
    {
        form: { 
            utente: "username", 
            j_password: "password"
        }
    }, 
    function (error, response, body) { 
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
             console.log(body); 
         } 
    } 
);`

...but it doesn't seems to working. How do I log into the page?

Comment: What error do you get? Also, are you sure if the target page takes URL encoded form, and not a JSON or other body type?

Comment: @Vasan it just return the body of the page with a paragraph "The page you are searching is not avaible"

Comment: Without knowledge of the form's contract, it will be difficult to answer your question. From the error message it seems the page itself does not exist, so perhaps you need to check the URL. Or it could be a poorly configured message in response to a different error. If possible, try it from a browser or rest client to see if it works that way first.